# Static front page as parent of with child pages?

Tags: frontpage, customization

I am trying to produce a static front page that has child pages, so that the menu looks like the following:

---

About (static front page, parent page of "CV" and "Address")
   -CV (child of "About")
   -Address (child of "About")
Other page 1
Other page 2 (parent of "sub 1" and "sub 2")
-sub 1 (child of "Other page 2")
-sub 2 (child of "Other page 2")

---

What works is to use "About" as the parent. My problem is, that "CV" and "Address" are shown in the menu as separate items, not as children of "About", even though their parent-entry correctly says "About". Here's the menu:

---

About (static front page)
      Other page 1
      Other page 2 (parent of "sub 1" and "sub 2")
      -sub 1 (child of "Other page 2")
      -sub 2 (child of "Other page 2")
CV
Address

---

What am I overlooking here?

Thanks ab bunch!
tef

Comment: Hi,!(http://s7.directupload.net/images/120905/69aqerwu.png) This is whagt it looks like: http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3004/wmheftix_png.htm

Comment: Args, this is not my day. Again:  

This is what it looks like (About is static front page): http://s1.directupload.net/images/120905/wmheftix.png   

This is what I want it to look like (but that only works when "About" is not a static front page):   http://s7.directupload.net/images/120905/69aqerwu.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you just outputting the pages for the navigation with wp_list_pages() or a similar function?

It might be better to use the Wordpress Menu feature and create a menu for the navigation, then use wp_nav_menu() to display it.

Alternatively, instead of setting a static page in the backend you can edit (or create) the home.php theme file and query the specific "About" page you want from within the template file, which shouldn't cause the problem you are encountering.

Comment: thanks a lot. Using the Menu feature already helped. I hadn't even looked at it and relied on whatever my theme did automatically when choosing "parent pages" for some of my static pages.